# How to get my site spammed?

Tags: spam, hacking, spamming

I know this might be an unusual question as most people will usually want the opposite as what I’m asking for, but I want to run an experiment and I would like to get my own site spammed.

Spam traffic, spam comments, potential hackings… anything and everything.
Which ways do you know to encourage this kind of behavior? Are there any forums where I can submit the site? Spam lists? Something of the sort?

If this information helps the site will run on WordPress on a dedicated server.

P.D. For those of you who might be thinking I’m asking for help pissing a competitor or someone off by ruining their site this is not the case. I’m currently setting up this test site. Once its up I’ll be happy to provide proof that the site is my own.

Comment: As someone who set up traps and triggers to encourage spam and hacker traffic for research, I do not want these tricks out in the wild to be used against other sites as a weapon. It stands to reason that answering this question could be used to harm others. If you were a researcher, you would already know how to answer this question enough to get you a good start. I am concerned why you are asking this question. Without expertise, you will be opening yourself up to issues you cannot handle.

Comment: I am of the opinion that this is a good question.   Honeypots are a very useful tool and instructions for setting them up would be useful in many legitimate situations.  There are even answers to this question that would be more about setting up your site such as "install WordPress" or "don't use captcha" that wouldn't be useful for launching attacks against competitors that have good practices.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There is plenty of information in creating a honey site. Going beyond that is dangerous. It is far better that the OP research the topic. From experience, I would not go beyond setting up a honeypot as described on the net. For example, a hosted site with WP can increase the probability that the site will be hacked. I used 2 firewalls with deep packet inspection and HTTP filtering along with a protocol gap and a hardened system with a custom coded protocol interface to ensure that no harm could be done. All requests to the system were filtered with redundancy.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller As well, the web is designed as a trust first protocol. I had to flip this programmatically so that any unanticipated hack attempt was dropped before being allowed. This means no request could be progress without passing the filters so that by default all accesses were deemed unsafe before being allowed.

Comment: Apart from the motives and repercussions, this question is really too [broadly-scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), and will generate [discussion-based lists](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is off-topic for this site. Questions here should be about single issues and problems that can be answered in brief, with a possible best answer so that it can be voted on by the community and accepted as such.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use WordPress for a honeypot, which is what I think you want to do. I'd just build a quick informational site with a commenting system that doesn't do email verification or captcha. Also put an open mailto link on it for people to use if they have problems posting. Post a link to the domain wherever you can, as well as a link to the email address. Then disable spam filtering, and you should be swimming in spam in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Its weird.

Submit your site to some website which automatically build link o your site. Maximum they will be low quality link.